# abstract is not located in suitable place!

Tags: positioning, abstract

As you can see, the abstract location (in persian we say چکیده) is not in suitable place.
What should I do?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont={sf,bf}, margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushright}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{2}\bfseries}{\thesection--}{1em}{}
\newcommand*{\TitleFont}{%
      \usefont{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}%
      \fontsize{19}{2}%
      \selectfont}
\usepackage{multicol} % for text in multiple columns
\setlength\columnsep{6mm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{ptext} % random text generator
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{HM XZar}
\setmainlanguage{farsi}
%\setotherlanguage{english}

\title{ \TitleFont{\textbf{عنوان مقاله} } }
\parindent 0.5cm
\date{بهمن ماه 1394}
\author{حسین بهبودی}
\begin{document}
        \maketitle
    \begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{2cm}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent
\ptext[1]
\end{abstract}
    \end{adjustwidth}
%       \noindent
    \begin{multicols}{2}
\section{اولین عنوان}
        \ptext[1-2] % generates several paragraphs of random text
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by executing `\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushright}` along with embedding the `abstract` environment inside a `changepage` environment?

Comment: Could that be a design choice of this template you are using? And where would you like the "Abstract" text to be?

Comment: @Mico : without the code, the abstract will be at the center. But I want it in the right.

Comment: @hbaderts I want it in the right but with same margin as the abstract text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot really test your example file because I do not have the font. So here is a Latin Modern Roman example.

The issue is that the abstract is set in a list environment while the abstract title stuff is not. The list environment makes it easy to modify the margins of the abstract text, but it also means that the `\abstractname` is not so easily modified.

Thus, one solution would be to put the `\abstractname` into the same environment, which I have done below. (See the lines marked `<-- ADDED`.) Please note: This is a non-portable and ad hoc solution for getting a flushright `\abstractname` with the same margins as the text of the abstract.

I have commented out some of your code to make the example compile. I hope switching it back to the font `HM XZar` and the package `xepersian` doesn't change things. If it does, please edit the question to use a font that others are likely to have.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont={sf,bf}, margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushright}
% Use these commands rather than the adjustwidth environment
\setlength{\absleftindent}{2cm}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{2cm}
% \setlength{\abstitleskip}{<length>}% <-- use if space between abstract title and abstract is too large/small

\makeatletter
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
    \if@bsrunin
    \else
      \if@bsstyle
        \abstitlestyle{\abstractname}
      \else
        \ifnumber@bs
          \num@bs
        \else
          \begin{@bstr@ctlist}% <-- ADDED
          \begin{\absnamepos}\abstractnamefont\abstractname\end\absnamepos%
          \end{@bstr@ctlist}%   <-- ADDED
        \fi
      \fi
      \vspace{\abstitleskip}%
    \fi
    \put@bsintoc%
    \begin{@bstr@ctlist}\if@bsrunin\@bsrunintitle\fi\abstracttextfont}%
    {\par\end{@bstr@ctlist}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{2}\bfseries}{\thesection--}{1em}{}
\newcommand*{\TitleFont}{%
      \usefont{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}%
      \fontsize{19}{2}% <-- this is wrong...
      \selectfont}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\setlength\columnsep{6mm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
%\usepackage{ptext} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum} % <-- added for the example
%\usepackage{xepersian}
%\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
%\settextfont{HM XZar}
%     \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
% \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Numbers=Arabic]{Amiri}
%\setmainlanguage{farsi}
%\setotherlanguage{english}

\title{Title}
\parindent 0.5cm
\date{1234}
\author{Ann Author}
\begin{document}
        \maketitle
%    \begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{2cm}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
%    \end{adjustwidth}
%       \noindent

    \begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Section}
        \lipsum
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```